# How can I Increase Internet Speeds?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

In my house there are two users of the internet, me and my sister. When my sister doesn't use her phone I get faster speeds but when she starts using it my speed drastically decreases.

I know that when many users are on the same internet connection, eventually the internet speed should decrease but what happens here is when she browses she gets good speed and mine becomes very slow. I want the opposite to happen, I want my internet speed to be good and hers bad.

We both use a WiFi connection and I am closer to the WiFi modem and she is further away, but I am still slower.

Our internet speed is generally 8 Mbps, but after consuming a lot it gets reduced to 1 Mbps. When I check the speed on my sister's iPhone it is around 1 Mbps, but in my case when I open the task manager (in Windows) I see that my speed keeps dropping to 0Kbps and never goes over 200Kbps!

The Wifi adapter in my PC is **Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter** and my sister uses an iPhone. [We use a TP-Link Archer C7 Router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BUSDVBQ).

Is there any way to increase my speed or any third party (*safe*) software to boost Google Chrome?

Comment: This is called packet prioritization, and a standard for handling prioritization is QoS (which stands for "quality of service", because certain types of traffic would be given priority so that that traffic would achieve necessary amounts of quality).  Research that to see if your router supports it.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the make and model of your wifi router? Do you get the same disruption if you use an ethernet cable to connect your PC to the internet?

Comment: and yes i face the problem even after using ethernet cable @Burgi

Comment: What model of iPhone is it? You should also investigate the QoS settings on the router as suggested by @TOOGAM.

Comment: iphone 6 with ios 8, how to investigate QoS settings

Comment: You investigate the QoS settings by logging into your router to see if the setting is available or not.

Comment: Can you use an Ethernet cable? I'm not trolling, if you are close to the modem, it is cheap and will always be more reliable than wireless.

Comment: I used Ethernet but still no difference

Comment: Could the 1mbps restriction come from your ISP after you exceed a certain threshold?  These are common in more rural areas and in certain countries.

Answer (score 1):

While your router (TP-LINK Archer C7 AC1750) does not support QOS, it supports bandwidth control which allows you to specify per device limits that could allow you to limit your sister's connection speed.

Answer (score 0):

Update your browser time to time. If you continue to use an old version of a browser, you'll eventually begin to notice that your Internet seems slower, since the old browser isn't equipped to handle new content. Solve the problem by updating to a current browser. If you are using internet browser then download the latest version.

Start by deleting your temporary internet data. This is usually very simple; guides for whatever browser you use can be found with a quick Google search. Afterward, go through your programs and remove those you no longer use or want.

Unplug and remove battery from your computer then carefully open the case and then clean it out with cotton swabs and compressed air. Sometimes it can cause to bulk the problem is just a huge dust dummy.